# Google Cloud Speech NoSuchFieldError: CONTEXT_SPAN_KEY

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I'm getting an error while trying to use the google-cloud-speech library.

It's probably about my dependencies. The library was working seamlessly before adding firebase authentication dependencies. So it's probably about the [endpoints-management-control-appengine-all](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.endpoints/endpoints-management-control-appengine-all) dependency.

Stackdriver logs:

> com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception
>   occurred while calling backend method (SystemService.java:373)
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   CONTEXT_SPAN_KEY at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:62)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.longrunning.OperationFutureImpl.get(OperationFutureImpl.java:127)
>   at
>   com.codefan.backend.util.AudioRecognizer.getRecognizedSpeechResults(AudioRecognizer.java:45)
>   at
>   com.codefan.backend.util.SubtitleGenerator.generate(SubtitleGenerator.java:34)
>   at
>   com.codefan.backend.endpoint.SubtitleApi.generateSubtitles(SubtitleApi.java:92)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:349)
>   at
>   com.google.api.server.spi.handlers.EndpointsMethodHandler$RestHandler.handle(EndpointsMethodHandler.java:127)
>   at
>   com.google.api.server.spi.handlers.EndpointsMethodHandler$RestHandler.handle(EndpointsMethodHandler.java:110)
>   at
>   com.google.api.server.spi.dispatcher.PathDispatcher.dispatch(PathDispatcher.java:50)
>   at
>   com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.service(EndpointsServlet.java:80)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:287)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:277)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:182)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
>   at
>   com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
>   at com.google.api.control.ConfigFilter.doFilter(ConfigFilter.java:125)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
>   at
>   com.google.api.control.ControlFilter.doFilter(ControlFilter.java:229)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119)
>   at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)
>   at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)
>   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.ParseBlobUploadHandler.handle(ParseBlobUploadHandler.java:119)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1182)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doHandle(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:183)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:293)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539) at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333) at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:213)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:692)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:655)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:625)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:817)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:269)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CONTEXT_SPAN_KEY at
>   io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor.interceptCall(CensusTracingModule.java:384)
>   at
>   io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156)
>   at
>   io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor.interceptCall(CensusStatsModule.java:690)
>   at
>   io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcChannelUUIDInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcChannelUUIDInterceptor.java:52)
>   at
>   io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:80)
>   at
>   io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.java:55)
>   at
>   io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156)
>   at
>   io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:789)
>   at
>   io.grpc.internal.ForwardingManagedChannel.newCall(ForwardingManagedChannel.java:63)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcClientCalls.newCall(GrpcClientCalls.java:90)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectCallable.futureCall(GrpcDirectCallable.java:58)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable.futureCall(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:64)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.rpc.AttemptCallable.call(AttemptCallable.java:86)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingCallable.futureCall(RetryingCallable.java:63)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingCallable.futureCall(RetryingCallable.java:41)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcOperationSnapshotCallable.futureCall(GrpcOperationSnapshotCallable.java:58)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.tracing.TracedUnaryCallable.futureCall(TracedUnaryCallable.java:75)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.tracing.TracedOperationInitialCallable.futureCall(TracedOperationInitialCallable.java:61)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.rpc.OperationCallableImpl.futureCall(OperationCallableImpl.java:82)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.tracing.TracedOperationCallable.futureCall(TracedOperationCallable.java:78)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.rpc.OperationCallable$1.futureCall(OperationCallable.java:150)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.rpc.OperationCallable.futureCall(OperationCallable.java:67)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.longRunningRecognizeAsync(SpeechClient.java:360)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.longRunningRecognizeAsync(SpeechClient.java:320)
>   at
>   com.codefan.backend.util.AudioRecognizer.getRecognizedSpeechResults(AudioRecognizer.java:39)
>   ... 57 more

Here's the `AudioRecognizer` class' only method:

```
@Override
public List<SpeechRecognitionResult> getRecognizedSpeechResults(String sourceLang, int sampleRate, String gcsUri) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create();

    RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
            .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.FLAC)
            .setLanguageCode(sourceLang)
            .setSampleRateHertz(sampleRate)
            .setEnableWordTimeOffsets(true)
            .build();

    RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setUri(gcsUri).build();

    // Use non-blocking call for getting file transcription
    OperationFuture<LongRunningRecognizeResponse, LongRunningRecognizeMetadata> speechRecResponse = speechClient.longRunningRecognizeAsync(config, audio);
    while (!speechRecResponse.isDone()) {
        logger.warning("Waiting for response...");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }

    return speechRecResponse.get().getResultsList();
}
```

Project's dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
        <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
        <artifactId>endpoints-framework-guice</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [START api_management] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
        <artifactId>endpoints-management-control-appengine-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [END api_management] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-speech</artifactId>
        <version>0.87.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-translate</artifactId>
        <version>1.69.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [START Objectify_Dependencies] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [END Objectify_Dependencies] -->
    <!-- [START Test_Dependencies] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [END Test_Dependencies] -->
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add api management, I walked through [this post](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management). It indicates using *endpoints-management-control-appengine-all* library.

Later on, when I checked this library's compile dependencies, I couldn't see any. They probably stuffed the codes inside the library without using any dependencies, that's why it has the indicator *-all*, I guess. This leads to having multiple instances of the same classes. Since no dependencies are defined, maven can't pick a single one among multiple dependencies.

In a nutshell, this is caused by classes being scanned from multiple locations.

Luckily, there are alternatives to this library. Here are the dependencies, I am using for api management right now.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
    <artifactId>endpoints-management-control-appengine</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
    <artifactId>endpoints-framework-auth</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

And probably having less code in my project, since I am not adding *all* the things.